# ¿Modificar arreglo de objetos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

¿Alguien sabe como modificar los elementos de un arreglo de objetos en javascript?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo un arreglo como este:

```
var resultado = [{name: "id", type: "string"},{name: "fecha", type: "string"},{name: "puesto", type: "string"},{name: "nombre", type: "string"}];
```

Lo que necesito hacer es cambiar el type de fecha a date.

El array que espero como resultado es el siguiente:

```
 var resultado = [{name: "id", type: "string"},{name: "fecha", type: "date"},{name: "puesto", type: "string"},{name: "nombre", type: "string"}];
```

Mi siguiente código logra cambiar el type a date pero no puedo obtener el name "fecha" alguien sabe donde estoy mal.

```js
var resultado = [{name: "id", type: "string"},{name: "fecha", type: "date"},{name: "puesto", type: "string"},{name: "nombre", type: "string"}];


// Recorro mi arreglo para obtener los datos
for(var n =0; n<resultado.length; n++)
{
  resultado[1]= {name:n, type:'date'}; // logro cambiar el type a date pero ya no obtengo "fecha".
  console.log("array resultado", resultado[n]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te funciona por que le estás asignando a la propiedad `name` el valor de `n` y `n` es una variable numérica que sirve como contador para controlar el ciclo `for`.

Además de esto, no necesitas volver a estructurar todo el objeto, solo basta con seleccionar la propiedad que deseas modificar y asignarle su nuevo valor:

```js
var resultado = [{name: "id", type: "string"},{name: "fecha", type: "string"},{name: "puesto", type: "string"},{name: "nombre", type: "string"}];

for(var n =0; n < resultado.length; n++){
  resultado[1].type = 'date';
  console.log("array resultado", resultado[n]);
}
```